# Poetry with a path depedency on a package with a path dependencies

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I have the following structure

```
package-a
   src/company/package_a/something.py
   pyproject.toml

package-b
   src/company/package_b/something.py
   pyproject.toml

package-c
   src/company/package_c/something.py
   pyproject.toml
```

Now package-b depends on package-a by:

```
package-a = { path = "../package-a/", develop = true }
```

Which installs fine. Now package-c depends on package-a and package-b, with:

```
package-a = { path = "../package-a/", develop = true }
package-b = { path = "../package-a/", develop = true }
```

Which install package-a fine, but gives errors when installing package-b:

```
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hz7rabwo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\packages\directory_dependency.py", line 41, in __init__
          raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
      ValueError: Directory ..\package-a does not exist
```

How to resolve this? The strange thing is that it does work when I use the same `poetry.lock` file in my docker. Is this related to `--use-feature=in-tree-build` of pip?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1168#issuecomment-714777590), i.e. duplicate your dependency `package-a` in the dev dependencies, so that it is a path dependency only in dev. Maybe this helps, maybe it does not. -- In my experience, path dependencies should be used only for dev dependencies and not for normal dependencies.